# Why undefiner reference?

Tags: c++, undefined-reference

In my `test.cpp` I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "first.h"
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    auto dliste = d::data_preparation::prepare_d(100);
    cout << "Hello World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

In my `first.h` I have:

```
namespace d {
    namespace data_preparation {
        something;
        std::vector<row<mdata::dliste>> prepare_d(int f);
        something;
    }
}
```

In my `first.cpp` I have:

```
#include "first.h"
something;
namespace d {
    namespace data_preparation {
        vector<row<mdata::dliste>> prepare_d(int f) {
            vector<row<mdata::dliste>> dliste;
            cout << f << '\n';
            return dliste;
        }
    }
}
```

When I compile this I get:

> undefined reference to
>   `d::data_preparation::prepare_d(int)'

**EDITED**

In my `Makefile` I have:

```
test: test.o
        $(CXX) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS)
```

Should I modify it somehow?

Comment: Did you link first.cpp?

Comment: @billz, I do not know. How can I link first.cpp? I thought that I include "first.h" and "first.h" includes "first.cpp" and, as a consequence, "first.cpp" should be visible from "test.cpp".

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: @Roman, add the space character between `>>` in `std::vector<row<mdata::dliste>> prepare_d(int f);` i.e. `std::vector<row<mdata::dliste> > prepare_d(int f);` and other similar lines. Many C++ compilers interpret `>>` in this case as operator `>>`.

Answer (score 2):

You have most likely forgot to link `first.cpp` to your executable.

Just run this commands (if you are using gcc):

```
g++ -c first.cpp -o first.o
g++ -c test.cpp -o test.o
g++ test.o first.o
```

Or just use the compact version:

```
g++ first.cpp test.cpp -o app
```

---

You should edit your Makefile along the lines of:

```
app: test.o first.o
    $(CXX) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)

test.o: test.cpp
    $(CXX) -c test.cpp -o first.o

first.o: first.cpp
    $(CXX) -c first.cpp -o first.o
```

*Notice: I'm forced to use 4 spaces for indentation but Makefile may require tabs instead.*

Comment: Jueecy, I use Make file. Could you please tell me how I should modify it. I put some more details to my question.